# Register using previously registered type

Tags: autofac

I have the following code that I am converting from Ninject to Autofac:

```cs
kernel.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
    .As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerApiRequest();
kernel.RegisterType<TokenHelper>().As<ITokenHelper>();

kernel.Register(c => {
    var tokenHelper = // Ninject code: kernel.Get<ITokenHelper>();
    var httpContextBase = // Ninject code: kernel.Get<HttpContextBase>();
    var token = tokenHelper.GetToken(httpContextBase);

    var connectionContext = // Ninject code: kernel.Get<ISqlServerConnectionContext>();
    connectionContext.Token = token;

    return token;
}).As<IMinimalSecurityToken>();
```

In my IMinimalSecurityToken registration, how do I tell Autofac to use the previously defined types to return an instance for tokenHelper and httpContextBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Register` method the `c` parameter is an instance of a `IComponentContext` implementation which is the container in which the component is being created.

So the `c` instance has [all the necessary extension methods](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Component-Creation#wiki-expressions) to resolve your previously registered types:

```cs
kernel.Register(c => {
    var tokenHelper = c.Resolve<ITokenHelper>();
    var httpContextBase = c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();
    var token = tokenHelper.GetToken(httpContextBase);

    var connectionContext = c.Resolve<ISqlServerConnectionContext>();
    connectionContext.Token = token;

    return token;
}).As<IMinimalSecurityToken>();
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I have no idea why it did not occur to me to examine just what 'c' was.